# Proof about existence subgraph in graph

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

I need help with my math problem.

Let $G$ be a graph with $n$ nodes and more than $\dfrac{3 (n - 1)}{2} $ links. Show that $G$ contains some $\theta a,b,c$ graph as its subgraph.

$\theta a, b, c$  is graph with three paths.

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me. $G$ has at least how many links? $3(n-1)$ or $2$? What is a $\theta a,b,c$ graph? Perhaps you would like to clarify.

Comment: I assume they mean a theta graph with paths a, b, and c?

Comment: How can i show that with induction??? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G$ be a counterexample with the smallest number of nodes, and with $e$ edges.  Hence $G$ is connected.  The average degree in $G$ is $$\frac{2e}{n}>\frac{3(n-1)}{n}=3-\frac{1}{n}.$$  Hence there is a vertex $v$ of degree $3$ or more in $G$.

- *Case I*: $v$ has three neighbors, $r$, $s$ and $t$, which belong to the same connected component in $G \setminus v$.  By assumption, there is a path from $r$ to $s$ not including $v$.

  [image]

  There must also be a path from $t$ to $s$ not including $v$ (or $t$ might even belong to $P$).  Thus, there is a shortest path from $t$ to a vertex in $P$.

  [image]

  Together, these identify a theta subgraph.
- *Case II*: $G \setminus v$ consists of the connected components $C_1,C_2,\ldots,C_k,D_1,D_2,\ldots,D_s$, where any $C_i$ contains exactly one neighbor of $v$ and any $D_i$ contains exactly two neighbors of $v$.

  Suppose $C_i$ has $a_i$ edges and $b_i$ vertices, and suppose $D_i$ has $\overline{a}_i$ edges and $\overline{b}_i$ vertices.  Then the number of edges in $G$ is $$e=\sum_{i=1}^k a_i+\sum_{i=1}^s \overline{a}_i+k+2s$$ and the number of vertices is $$n=\sum_{i=1}^k b_i+\sum_{i=1}^s \overline{b}_i+1.$$

  If $a_i+1 > \frac{3}{2}b_i$ for any $i \in \{1,2,\ldots,k\}$, then the subgraph induced by $C_i \cup \{v\}$ is a smaller counterexample.  Hence $a_i \leq \frac{3}{2}b_i-1$ for all $i \in \{1,2,\ldots,k\}$.

  If $\overline{a}_i+2 > \frac{3}{2}\overline{b}_i$ for any $i \in \{1,2,\ldots,s\}$, then the subgraph induced by $D_i \cup \{v\}$ is a smaller counterexample.  Hence $\overline{a}_i \leq \frac{3}{2}\overline{b}_i-2$ for all $i \in \{1,2,\ldots,s\}$.

  Hence
  \begin{align*}
   e & = \sum_{i=1}^k a_i+\sum_{i=1}^s \overline{a}_i+k+2s \\
     & \leq \sum_{i=1}^k \left(\frac{3}{2}b_i-1\right)+\sum_{i=1}^s \left(\frac{3}{2}\overline{b}_i-2\right)+k+2s & \text{as explained above} \\
     & = \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{3}{2}b_i+\sum_{i=1}^s \frac{3}{2}\overline{b}_i-(k+2s)+k+2s \\
     & \leq \frac{3}{2}(n-1).
   \end{align*}
  This contradicts that $G$ is, in fact, a counterexample.